Reference for: if $G$ is nilpotent and $N[H,G]=H$, then $N=H$.
A question regarding a similar this has already been asked and answered:
If $G$ is a nilpotent group and $H\leq G$ with $H[G,G]=G$ then $H=G$.
However, what I am asking for a reference of a slight generalization.
Let $G$ is nilpotent, and $H,N$ subgroups of $G$, with $N$ normal. If  $N[H,G]=H$, then $N=H$.
The proof for this is very similar to the less general case: if $H[G,G]=G$, then $H=G$.
Does anyone know where I can find a reference for this, let's call it, Lemma?
Thanks in advance.

How about $G=\langle a,b \mid a^4=b^2=(ab)^2=1\rangle = D_8$, $H=\langle a^2,b \rangle$, $K=\langle b \rangle$?

You are right, I think I we need $K$ to be $G$-invariant, i.e. normal.

In that case your should edit the question.

Moding out by $N$, you are trying to show that $[H,G]=H$ implies $H$ trivial.

IMO the most likely reference will be found after applying Arturo's simplification. Then the result you need is just $[H,i G]\le\gamma{i+1}(G)$, which can be found many books (personally I'd try Hall's nilpotent group notes). But also this is trivial to prove directly.

This is Exercise 1.5(i) in Susan McKay's Finite $p$-groups, Queen Mary Maths Notes 18., p. 9
